# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, windows-10

I want to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10, but I wouldn't have written this question if everything went OK. I am getting a list of errors and the system crashes every time I start the installation of Ubuntu.

Given:

I have Windows 10 Home installed on my desktop.
The system supports UEFI and Legacy for boot.

Steps I performed:

1. Downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Using Rufus I made bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 20.04 installation.
3. In boot priority from BIOS, gave USB drive priority over other drives.
4. After the system rebooted, I chose Ubuntu to install.

Expected:

Proceed to install Ubuntu.

Actual:

A list of ACPI errors were displayed and the system crashed.

[image]

Some details:

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 20.04
- UEFI firmware
- Rufus to make a bootable drive
- USB 3.0 drive - Sandisk

Questions:

- What can be wrong? Can it be USB, or maybe Rufus made crack? Is there anything else?
- Should I allocate memory first? (I know that it can be done during the Ubuntu installation.)

Comment: Another thing - ACPI errors can be triggered by components incompatibilities. I am using RTX-2060 video card. Can it be the cause?

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI Secure Boot? Are you starting the live image in graphic mode? Have you tried safe graphics?

Comment: Is your desktop firmware the latest from the vendor?  Did you get the ahci drivers for Windows and turn off raid mode in the UEFI settings?

Comment: Please see if this link helps, https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot
Pay attention to the following remark:
** if your Windows 10 installation is not correctly shutdown or is hibernating, has corrupted partition which needs repair, partition has not enough free disk space left for resizing, uses Dynamic Disk or the file system contains uncontrollable file fragmentation**
it is likely to fail.

Comment: Thanks every one for response on my questions. Huge thumbs up to @Ginnungagap. Safe graphics worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ginnungagap adviced, I kicked off ubuntu with safe graphic mode and it worked for me.